# How to use SVN folder / files normally just to trace it without committing / rollback effects on it

Tags: php, svn

I have got one folder from someone with SVN and I have to look into this (I want to trace it with changes in code but for temporaty only and dont want to save any of the changes done by me) on my local server.

Now the issue arise is eventhough I have copied that folder to anywhere in my system, it is showing with SVN tick mark and in case I make any change,it showing red symbol (might be because I havent saved any changes as I just want to trace the code by adding comment and so).

Hence,How can I use that folder on my local server just like other normal folders ? I have tried to search but could not got any specific information for this.

Comment: If he gave you a checkout of the code, it won't include history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with

> right click on SVN folder -> TortoiseSVN  -> Export .
>
> Create one folder and Export it there.
>
> And you can find all those file in that created folder.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove all the `.svn` folders, *which are hidden* , from all the folders that you have got. Normally a windows search for `.svn` folder and delete does the trick.

A better way to do this is to ask your friend to "Export" instead of "Checkout"!

**EDIT 1**
If you want to keep the `.svn` folders for keeping the repository information and assuming you are using Tortoise SVN , you can try below

> Right Click > TortoiseSVN > Settings > Icon Overlays > Exclude Path > Full Path

This is assuming that you have Tortoise SVN. This however will still link your repository with remote SVN repository, and may allow you to update/commit the files. You have been warned!

Comment: Isnt it create issue on actual folder if delete hidden folder from it ?

Comment: .svn folder holds the svn related information alone. Do you want to keep the .svn folders so that you dont lose that information, but dont want to see the tick marks also?

Comment: I dont want to use that folder as svn at all, it should like just a simple folder of project on our localhost and whenever i made any changes in any of files, it should not commit / rollback code. In short its just code took from live but i want to use it as my local system folder and don't want to get affected any live svn folder due to any of my changes.But when I copied that folder to my local or anywhere,its still showing with tick and any of my changes are showing there,so it means those changes are updating to actual live files ?

Comment: I hope you are using Tortoise SVN. And the removal of .svn is the way to ensure that you dont accidentally checkin or update the files. Because that will ensure there is no link between your repository and the file system. Nevertheless I am updating the answer which does not include the removal of .svn as well.